# generate a unique ID in c#

Tags: c#, session, variables

I tried to generate a unique ID starting from 1 but the number stays the same..
I'm trying to use session variable so it can go like 1,2,3,4...

Main page:

```
protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int bookingID = 0;
    bookingID += 1;
    bookingIDTextBox.Text = bookingID.ToString();
}
protected void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["confirmBooking"] = "confirm";
    Session["bookingID"] = bookingIDTextBox.Text;
    Response.Redirect("MainBookingForm.aspx");
}
```

Second page:

```
protected void newBookingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bookingRef = (string)(Session["bookingID"]);
    Session["bookingRef"] = bookingRef;
    Response.Redirect("BookingForm.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Apparently you have a session. Why not increment the number on the session? Your latest identity is known already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the variable each time you press the button, so it will always be 1

Declare the variable outside the method

```
int bookingID = 0;
protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    bookingID += 1; // You can also use bookingID++
    bookingIDTextBox.Text = bookingID.ToString();
}
```

EDIT note that it will be reset when you restart the application, you might want to store it somewhere (application settings / database etc)

Comment: Thank you. I think all sorted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Application object - it is part of the HttpContext and is directly accessible on any page.

If you don't want to use it, you may want to write a Globals class (or whatever name you like) that holds static members.

```
public class Globals
{
  public static int Counter { get; set;}
}

// accessed from other classes:
Globals.Counter++;
```

Comment: Note that this will be reset whenever the web-app recycles. You might want to keep this number in a database or something that survives a restart.